# central automorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory

‎Let ‎‎$‎‎C_{Aut_{c}(G)}(Z(G))$ ‎be ‎‎‎‎‎‎the group of all central automorphisms of finite non abelian $p$-group ‎$‎G‎$‎ fixing ‎$‎Z(G)‎$ element wise. If $‎‎C_{Aut_{c}(G)}(Z(G))$ is a proper subgroup of $Inn(G)$, then what can we say about $G$?
I know that $G$ is not of class two.

Comment: It would be good to remind people that an automorphism $\phi$ of $G$ is a central automorphism if $\phi(x)x^{-1}\in Z(G)$ for all $x\in G$.

Comment: If $C_{{\rm Aut}_c(G)}(Z(G))={\rm Aut}_c(G)$, as is the case when $Z(G)$ has order 2, then there is nothing more that you can say. To see this choose $\phi\in{\rm Inn}(G)\setminus{\rm Aut}_c(G)$. If $\phi$ is conjugation by $g$, then there exists an $x\in G$ such that $x^gx^{-1}\not\in Z(G)$, because $\phi$ is not a central automorphism. This says that $G$ does not have nilpotency class 2. Hence you should assume $C_{{\rm Aut}_c(G)}(Z(G))$ is a proper subgroup of both ${\rm Aut}_c(G)$ *and* ${\rm Inn}(G)$.

Comment: It is not difficult to see that $Z(Inn(G)) \leq C_{Aut_{c}(G)}(Z(G)) \leq Aut_{c}(G)$ (see "FINITE GROUPS WITH CENTRAL AUTOMORPHISM GROUP OF MINIMAL ORDER"). Also we can check that if C_{Aut_{c}(G)}(Z(G)) wants to be a subgroup of $Inn(G)$ it should be equal to Z(Inn(G)) ... Thus I can ask my question in this way "If Z(Inn(G)) = C_{Aut_{c}(G)}(Z(G)) then what can I say about $G$?"